# Execution failed for task ':app:processFirebaseDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android

When I build my app in android studio it comes like this .

```
Build Output :


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processFirebaseDebugGoogleServices'.
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\src\firebase\google-services.json
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\src\debug\google-services.json
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\src\firebaseDebug\google-services.json
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\src\firebase\debug\google-services.json
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\src\debug\firebase\google-services.json
D:\Github\ScreenStream-master\app\google-services.json

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
 log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }

 dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-rc01')
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72")
    classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
    classpath("com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:1.0.2")
    classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0")
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I already added the com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.

How can I solve this error ?

How to  switch to build variant FirebaseFree ?

Give a solution for this error.

Comment: You need to download google-services.json and add it to your working directory.

Comment: Where can I download the google-services.json and how to add ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file